# Custom css for modal with ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

The doc (https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-custom-css-class) says to use

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModalWithClass(template)">Open modal with custom css class</button>
<br>
 
<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Just a modal with a bunch of words inside, nothing serious.
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

and to show "template" in the function

```
openModalWithClass(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(
      template,
      Object.assign({}, { class: 'gray modal-lg' })
    );
```

But I created a component for the modal (too large for it to be in the same component) so there is no `#template` in the html, how can I import the #template id from my other html component ?

***Thank you very much !***

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to open a Modal Component from another Component, then this is the right way to do it with ngx-bootstrap:
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-component

Comment: The link doesn't open, you are talking about the second example of the Service Examples ?

Comment: Yes, 2nd option

Comment: That's what I did, but so how can I add the #template in the modal component ? I receive an error because the button is in one html component and the modal is in the other

Comment: #template is not needed, we have a dedicated component for the model ModalContentComponent

Comment: And so I can just add a scss styleUrls and custom it from there ?

Comment: want to apply the `modal-lg` with that ?

Comment: I need to custom the modal entirely based on given instructions (width, border and stuff), maybe I can just add a host in the component decorator

EDIT: doesn't work

Comment: As you can see in their example there is no .modal-content div, it's only the three divs header/body/footer and I need to select the .modal-content div

Comment: can't you use the class property of the `initialState` object which we are passing while show() ? in that you can create your style and apply it.

Comment: Hi, I added a class property in the initialState but it doesn't affect the class to the modal, I'm thinking about moving it back to the same component but it bothers me...

Comment: Just made it work by adding in the openModal function     this.bsModalRef.setClass('my-class') and import the style in main style.scss of the app :)